# How do I handle a ManyToMany relationship in JSON?

Tags: json, core-data, many-to-many

This is a follow-up question to my previous question on "[Managing employee contracts in a many-to-many relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967843/core-data-managing-employee-contracts-in-a-many-to-many-relationship)" and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410595/core-data-building-a-nspredicate-from-a-manytomany-relationship)

I have a relationship that can be explained thusly:

`company --< contracts >-- employees`

I am importing the data through JSON.  For simplicity sake it is shown below.

```
{
  "companies" : [
    {
      "name" : "Company A",
      "employees" : [
        {
          "name" : "Tom",
          "contract" : {
            "length" : "10",
            "salary" : "10000"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem is, I am not sure if this is correct.

In my Model relationship the `contract` sits between `company` and `employees` whereas in my above code I've put it as an object and it sits as a child under the employees.

Therefore, my question is, where should a junction table sit within the JSON feed?

Should it sit as a parent to employees, or is it okay where it is?

I'm not sure if I am doing it right and would welcome any help/thoughts on the best way to structure/layout a JSON feed that is reliant upon a junction table.

I know it may seem silly, but I'm trying to ascertain best standards when dealing with junction tables.

Thanks.

Edit.

**Purpose/Context**

I am attempting to read in JSON into Core data using TouchJSON.  Apologies for not clarifying the context earlier.  Updated tags.

I read the JSON into a NSDictionary.  If I start to separate the objects out I am not sure how to make TouchJSON/iOS understand the context of each relationship when it comes to parse/read the data into memory.

Comment: I think it depends on what you want to do with the data, how you want to process it...

Comment: I am hoping to grab the data from the feed and put it into Core data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this without foreign keys is to duplicate one side of the 'many' entities in your relationship.  Based on your example above, this would mean duplicating employees throughout the data structure.

You can really only get around this problem the same way that your relational database gets around the problem - with a mapping table and foreign keys.

```
{
  "companies" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Company A"
    }
  ],

  "employees" : [
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Fred"
    }
  ],

  "contracts" : [
    {
      "id" : 123,
      "company_id" : 1,
      "employee_id": 1
      "length" : 10,
      "salary" : 10000
    }
  ]
}
```

(As an aside, numerical values are valid in JSON, they do not need to be quoted)

The question, then, is if you have those keys available to you at the time of serialization.  If not, then you may need to assign some, if even temporarily for the purposes of the JSON, to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I do have keys as the JSON was created in a PHP app. But the problem is when I come to deserialize it in Core data/iOS as I'm not sure how to ensure that TouchJSON/iOS understands the context of each relationship at the time of reading.

Comment: Thinking more about this solution, would it mean I would need to put the API live, as I'd rather not do this and just use fixed files (in this case JSON).  I'm not sure how I'd make Core data/iOS understand all the relationships, etc unless I load the entire JSON feed into memory and then do a trawl through the various NSDictionaries to find matches.  It sounds rather labor-intensive and time-consuming.  If there is another way, I'm interested in at least looking at it.

Comment: @zardon How much data are we talking about here?

Comment: Not much, under 10k so its very small in terms of file size.  As I understand it there are 2 options.  1. Use an API to do all the cross-referencing and load in as required.  I want to avoid APIs for security reasons. 2. Load the flatfile JSON into a dictionary for each entity (a company dictionary, a contracts dictionary and employees dictionary) and then you use iOS to do the processing, and insert them as core data.   The thing I am not sure about is how to make it do the linking up. If there is an example available for this, I would look at it.

Comment: @zardon honestly, I am not familiar with core-data, so you're on your own there.  Ultimately though, the above representation maintains the relationships you have in the original relational database. I believe any other solution which does not maintain those relationships will be harder to deal with, in the long run.

Comment: I agree. Right now I'm just going down the road I am on at the moment where its likely there will be repeating data in the one big node of data.  Until I can figure out how (or pay some to) resolve the problem I'm not going to worry about it and just to the prototyping stage.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason your entity-relationship (E-R) model expresses many:many relationships via an associative entity is because the relational data model (a relational database being the most likely locus of your E-R model's implementation) can't directly express a many:many relationship — it requires an intersect table for a many:many relationship. Note that there are other reasons you might need such an intersect table (a contract, for instance, being an entity unto itself).

However, there's no reason that your object model has to suffer the constraints imposed by the relational database.

Comment: I'm happy with the entity relationship model, and I've tested it, it does resolve my requirements/problems; however the JSON thing is what puzzles me. Is it meant to reflect the structure of the relational database, and if I start to separate it, how does iOS understand the relationship context?

Comment: I've just decided to keep the app simplfied and try to avoid this situation where possible.

Comment: my 2 cents: JSON is no meant to reflect E-R model or a relational db, it's just a text list who can simulate a _hierarchical_ db.